# multi-line <span> tag inside a <u> tag being closing early

Tags: html

I am dealing with legacy HTML of the following type:

```
<pre>
     <u>blah <span class="cool">blah</u>
     <u>blah</span> blah</u>
</pre>
```

But the browser renders this as:

```
<pre>
     <u>blah <span class="cool">blah</span></u>
     <u>blah blah</u>
</pre>
```

The problem is that the `<span>` tag is closed early. Is there anything I can do to get the browser to render this as it should or is the legacy HTML badly formatted? Thanks!

Comment: The original HTML is not valid. `<u><span></u><u></span></u>` These tags are not nested in the correct order.

Comment: _"The problem is that the <span> tag is closed early"_ No it's not, you can't close an outer tag before closing the inner one. And it's not legacy HTML, it's invalid HTML. _"or is the legacy HTML badly formatted?"_ a yup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are closing the `span` tag after `u` tag.
I think this can solve your problem:

```
<pre>
    <span class="cool">
        <u>blah</u>
        <u>blah</u>
    </span>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you are trying to use is invalid, the browser is attempting to fix it. You are Closing the initial "u" tag while the span is open.

You can use this resource:

**The W3C Markup Validation Service**

https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: thanks for your help guys wish I could accept more than one answer